# Flexdashboard checkbox flows off page

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

I created a datatable in a flexdashboard with a checkbox, but the checkbox flows off the page. I tried to adjust the padding {data-padding = 10} but nothing changed. Below is the code and a picture of what the dashboard looks like. How do I move everything to the right so that it's aligned with the title of the page?

````
---
title: "School Dashboard"
author: "Shannon Coulter"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
    theme: spacelab
---
    ```{r}
    library(tidyverse)
    library(crosstalk)
    library(DT)
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```
    
    Student Lookup 
    ================================================================================
      
    ### Chronic Absenteeism Lookup
    
    ```{r ca-lookup, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    ican_tab <- tibble(
      year = c("2022", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2022"),
      date = c("March", "March","March","March","March"),
      school = c("ABC", "CDE","ABC","DEF","GHI"),
      grade = c("6th", "7th","8th","4th","5th"),
      race_eth = c("White", "Hispanic","White","Filipino","White"),
      abs_levels = c("Not At-Risk of Chronic Absenteeism", "At-Risk of Chronic Absenteeism",
                     "Severe Chronic Absenteeism", "Severe Chronic Absenteeism",
                     "Moderate Chronic Absenteeism")
    )
    
    sd <- SharedData$new(ican_tab)
    
    bscols(list(
      filter_checkbox("abs_levels", "Level", sd, ~ abs_levels, inline = TRUE),
      datatable(
        sd,
        extensions = c("Buttons",
                       "Scroller"),
        options = list(
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          scrollY = F,
          columnDefs = list(list(
            className = 'dt-center', 
            targets = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
          )),
          lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25, 100),
          dom = "Blrtip",
          deferRender = TRUE,
          scrollY = 300,
          scroller = TRUE,
          buttons = list('copy',
                         'csv',
                         'pdf',
                         'print')
        ),
        filter = "top",
        style = "bootstrap",
        class = "compact",
        width = "100%",
        colnames = c(
          "Year",
          "Date",
          "School",
          "Grade",
          "Race",
          "Level"
        )
      ) %>%
        formatStyle('abs_levels',
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(
                      unique(ican_tab$abs_levels),
                      c(
                        "#73D055ff",
                        "#95D840FF",
                        "#B8DE29FF",
                        "#DCE319FF"
                      )
                    ))
    ))
    ```
````

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to address this is probably to add style tags to your dashboard. You can put this anywhere. I usually put it right after the YAML or right after my first R chunk, where I just place my `knitr` options and libraries. This does not go inside an R chunk.

```
<style>
body {    /*push content away from far right and left edges*/
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
</style>
```

---

---

##### Update based on your updated question and comments

I don't have the content around your table, so I will give you a few options that work. For the most part, any one option won't be enough. You can mix and match the options that work best for you.

This is what I've got for the original table:

[image]

- Option 1: you can use CSS to push the table away from the edges (as in my original response
- Option 2: change the font sizes
- Option 3: constrain the size of the datatable htmlwidget
- Option 4: manually make the columns narrower
- Option 5: alter the filter labels (while keeping the same filters and data)

Aesthetically looks the best? It depends on what else is on the dashboard.

I think you will need the original CSS (option 1, in my original answer) regardless of what other options you choose to use.

Option 1 is above

###### Option 2

To change the font sizes, you have to modify the `filter_checkbox` and the `datatable` after they're made. Instead of presenting all of the programming code, I'm going to show you want to add or modify and how I broke down the objects.

Your original code for `filter_checkbox` remains the same. However, you'll assign it to an object, instead of including it in `bscols`.

Most of the code in your `datatable` will remain the same. there is an addition to the parameter `options`. I've included the original and change for that parameter.

```
# filter checkbox object
fc = filter_checkbox(...parameters unchanged...)
fc$attribs$style <- css(font.size = "90%") # <-change the font size

dt = datatable(
    ...
    ...
    options = list( # this will be modified
      autoWidth = TRUE,      # <- same
      scrollY = F,           # <- same
      initComplete = JS(          # <- I'M NEW! change size of all font
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().container()).css({'font-size': '90%'});",
        "}"),
      columnDefs = list(      # <- same
        list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(2, 3, 4, 5))),
      ... 
      ... # remainder of datatable and formatStyles() original code
 )

# now call them together
bscols(list(fc, dt))
```

The top version is with 90% font size, whereas the bottom is the original table.

[image]

###### Option 3

To constrain the size of the `datatable` widget, you'll need to create the object outside of `bscols`, like I did in option 2. If you were to name your widget `dt` as in my example, this is how you could constrain the widget size. This example sets the `datatable` to be 50% of the width and height viewer screen (or 1/4 of the webpage). Keep in mind that the filters are not part of the widget, so in all, the table is still more than 1/4th of the webpage. You will have to adjust the size for your purposes, of course. I recommend using a dynamic sizing mechanism like `vw`, `em`, `rem`, and the like.

```
dt$sizingPolicy$defaultWidth <- "50vw"
dt$sizingPolicy$defaultHeight <- "40vh"
```

The top image has options 1, 2, and 3; the bottom is the original table.

[image]

###### Option 4

To modify the width of the columns, you can add this modification to the parameter `options` in you call to `datatable`. This could be good, because most of the columns don't require as much width as the last column. However, if you change the font size or scale the table, it will change the font size dynamically, so this option may not be necessary.

Despite using `em` here, in the course of this going from R code to an `html_document`, it was changed to pixels. So this is *not* dynamically sized. (Not a great idea! Sigh!)

```
columnDefs = list(
        list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(2, 3, 4, 5)),
        list(width = '5em', targets = c(1,2,3,4,5))), # <- I'm NEW!
```

###### Option 5

For this option, I took the programming behind `crosstalk::filter_checkbox()` and modified the code a bit. I changed the function to `filter_checkbox2()`. If you use it, you can render it both ways and just keep the one you like better.

This first bit of code is the three functions that work together to create a `filter_checkbox` object with my modifications so that you can have a label that isn't exactly the same as the levels.

> It's important to note that the filters are alphabetized by `datatable`. It doesn't matter if they're factors, ordered, etc. If you use this new parameter `groupLabels`, they need to be in an order that aligns with the levels when they're alphabetized.

I put this code in an `include=F` chunk by itself:

```
# this is nearly identical to the original function
filter_checkbox2 = function (id, label, sharedData, group, 
                             groupLabels = NULL, # they're optional
                            allLevels = FALSE, inline = FALSE, columns = 1) {
    options <- makeGroupOptions(sharedData, group,
                                groupLabels, allLevels) # added groupLabels
    labels <- options$items$label
    values <- options$items$value
    options$items <- NULL
    makeCheckbox <- if (inline)
        inlineCheckbox
    else blockCheckbox
    htmltools::browsable(attachDependencies(tags$div(id = id,
        class = "form-group crosstalk-input-checkboxgroup crosstalk-input",
        tags$label(class = "control-label", `for` = id, label),
        tags$div(class = "crosstalk-options-group",
                 crosstalk:::columnize(columns,
            mapply(labels, values, FUN = function(label, value) {
                makeCheckbox(id, value, label)
            }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE))),
        tags$script(type = "application/json", `data-for` = id, 
                    jsonlite::toJSON(options, dataframe = "columns",
                                     pretty = TRUE))), 
        c(list(crosstalk:::jqueryLib()),crosstalk:::crosstalkLibs())))
    }

inlineCheckbox = function (id, value, label) { # unchanged
  tags$label(class = "checkbox-inline",
             tags$input(type = "checkbox",
                        name = id, value = value),
             tags$span(label))
  }    

# added groupLabels (optional)
makeGroupOptions = function (sharedData, group, groupLabels = NULL, allLevels) { 
    df <- sharedData$data(withSelection = FALSE, withFilter = FALSE,
        withKey = TRUE)
    if (inherits(group, "formula"))
        group <- lazyeval::f_eval(group, df)
    if (length(group) < 1) {
        stop("Can't form options with zero-length group vector")
    }
    lvls <- if (is.factor(group)) {
        if (allLevels) {levels(group) }
        else { levels(droplevels(group)) }
    }
    else { sort(unique(group)) }
    matches <- match(group, lvls)
    vals <- lapply(1:length(lvls), function(i) {
        df$key_[which(matches == i)]
    })
    lvls_str <- as.character(lvls)
    if(is.null(groupLabels)){groupLabels = lvls_str} # if none provided
    if(length(groupLabels) != length(lvls_str)){     # if the # labels != the # groups
      message("Warning: The number of group labels does not match the number of groups.\nGroups were used as labels.")
      groupLabels = lvls_str
    }
    options <- list(items = data.frame(value = lvls_str, label = groupLabels, # changed from lvls_str
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE), map = setNames(vals, lvls_str),
        group = sharedData$groupName())
    options
    }
```

When I used this new version of I changed `label = "Level"` to `label = "Chronic Absenteeism Level"`. Then removed " Chronic Absenteeism" from the filter labels. The data and the `datatable` does not change, just the filter checkbox labels.

```
filter_checkbox2("abs_levels", "Chronic Absenteeism Level", 
                      sd, ~ abs_levels, inline = TRUE,
                      groupLabels = unlist(unique(ican_tab$abs_levels)) %>%
                        str_replace(" Chronic Absenteeism", "") %>% sort())
```

The first image is your table with options 1, 2, 3, and 5 (not 4).

[image]

The top version in the next image has options 1, 2, 3, and 5 (not 4). The bottom is the original table. After that

[image]

If I've left anything unclear or if have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: This created more grey space between the edge of the page and the table, but the text is still cutoff.

Comment: What part of the text is cut off? When I worked on your question, I put the content into a script that I've used to answer other questions; it's got a lot of content! I also used `.datatables { /*for the crosstalk table*/ margin-right: 120px;}` because the right side of the table was running into another widget. Your question didn't include the data. I used the `diamonds` dataset. Without knowing what's around your table or in your table, the best I can offer is adding margin. Alternatively, [make your question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) for the best answer.

Comment: I apologize it's not a reproducible example. I shared a screenshot in the original post of what it looks like now. The dashboard has PII in it. I would need to adjust some things to create an reprex.

Comment: If you make a sample data set that emulates the real one, at least in that it's enough to cause the same problems that you're having, that's good enough for me!

Comment: I edited my original post to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer with multiple options for you to choose or not! They all work, but what works best for you only you know.